# Super key as shortcut - Openbox

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, desktop, openbox, window, desktop-shortcuts

I want to create the shortcuts:

- <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd>: Run `dmenu`
- <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd><kbd>← Left arrow</kbd>: Move current window to the left

I have both of them working, however when I depress <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> it opens `dmenu` right away. When
I then press <kbd>← Left arrow</kbd>, it moves the window.

Instead, I want pressing <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> and
<kbd>← Left arrow</kbd> without releasing <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> to move the window. `dmenu` should only start when <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> is pressed and released on it's own.

Is this possible? I know that it works well in gnome-shell and cinnamon, so there has to be a way.

Comment: What's your current config?

Answer (score 0):

my config is something like this (shortcuts that matter):

```
<keybind key="W">
  <action name="Execute">
      <command>dmenu_run</command>
  </action>
```

and the combination:

```
<keybind key="W-Left">
  <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
  <action name="MoveResizeTo">
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <height>97%</height>
    <width>50%</width>
  </action>
```

I were googling but didn't found anything to do the execution on release