# How to set a single modifier key as a shortcut in openbox?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-environment, openbox

I want to have my super key start `dmenu`.
I have set it as a keyboard shortcut in my `rc.xml` as follows:

```
<keybind key="0xffeb">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>dmenu_run</command>
      </action>
</keybind>
```

I tried specifying it in the `key` attribute as `W`, `W-`, and `0xffeb`, but none of these worked.
`W` responds to pressing the letter `w`, and the others appear to do nothing.

I want the shortcut to trigger when the super key is pressed and released on it's own. Is this possible?

---

*This is [cross posted](https://superuser.com/q/938294/319302) from super user as per the [guidelines here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87739/238438). I've read this question: [Super key as shortcut - Openbox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210661/86821), but I didn't see any useful information in it.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up using [xcape](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/xcape/), a utility designed to do exactly this:

> xcape allows you to use a modifier key as another key when pressed and released on its own. Note that it is slightly slower than pressing the original key, because the pressed event does not occur until the key is released.

<sup>Quoted from the [xcape readme](https://github.com/alols/xcape/blob/master/README.md)</sup>

Using xcape, you can assign the press *and release* of a modifier key to a different key or even a sequence of keys.
For example, you can assign <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> to a placeholder shortcut like <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> with:

```
xcape -e 'Super_L=Control_L|Shift_L|Alt_L|Super_L|D'
```

Now when you press and release <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> without pressing any other keys, xcape will send keyboard events simulating presses of <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (holding all the modifier keys down as if you pressed them like a shortcut).

If you press <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> *and* another key (or hold <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> too long, the default timeout is 500 ms), xcape will pass the keyboard events through as is, without firing extra keys.

If you put the placeholder shortcut in `rc.xml`, it will run when <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> and only <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> is pressed.

```
<keybind key="C-A-S-W-d">
      <action name="Execute">
          <command>dmenu_run</command>
      </action>
</keybind>
```

Other shortcuts involving <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> will not be affected.

Note that you'll have to run xcape each time you boot, so you may want to put it somewhere like `~/.config/openbox/autostart` where it will be run automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Run `xev` and press your super key to get the appropriate key name. Mine is `Super_L` according to the output:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0x91, subw 0x0, time 1648471775, (167,-8), root:(927,138),
    state 0x50, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Assuming yours is the same, this should work with a single key press of the super key (aka windows key):

```
<keybind key="Super_L">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>dmenu_run</command>
      </action>
</keybind>
```

Save the file and run `killall -SIGUSR2 openbox` to reload the configuration.

As an aside, I am working in the config file for the local user at `$HOME/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`. Using `W` only registers as the super key when used in combination, but `Super_L` works on its own instead of being read as the letter `w`.

Comment: This is closer, but it appears to run on key press instead of key release. So other shortcuts which use super no longer work..

Comment: I overlooked the release part. I would still like to know if there is a way to do this natively in openbox, because it seems like a feature that should be included. For example, it would be great if a chrooted keybinding could execute a command followed by breakchroot, all in one key press. Currently, all actions seem to require an additional key press. http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings#Chrooting_key_chains

Comment: Yes, that *would* be nice. If you find a way, I'll probably accept it ;) Though for now xcape is good enough for me.

Comment: It's a good thing you misunderstood the question and posted this answer. I'm sure that many people *were* looking for this.

Comment: Other shortcuts with super work for me, but they trigger only super shortcut.