# How to bind the Super-key to whiskermenu without breaking Super+Other combinations?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

Coming back from Windows 7 I'd like two kinds of shortcuts to work at the same time:

- Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> (a.k.a. <kbd>Super</kbd>) alone should open the whiskermenu e.g. for quick application launch
- Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + an arrow should provide the same behaviour as Windows does, i.e. Maximizing/Restoring, Minimizing, Tiling Left/Right

Unfortunately when I set up both the Window manager shortcuts for the latter and the keyboard application shortcut `xfce4-popup-whiskermenu` to <kbd>Super-L</kbd>, the Window manager combination are ignored and upon releasing the <kbd>Win</kbd> the whiskermenu opens nonetheless.

How can this be fixed?

(I'm running Arch Linux, if that is relevant)

Comment: Does it work if you use something like [`xbindkeys`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91433/22222) to set the `Win` -> `xfce4-popup-whiskermenu` shortcut?

Comment: @terdon Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work (I hope just running `xbindkeys` from a running session is sufficient, I didn't modify `.Xsession` and relog: "*** Warning ***
Please verify that there is not another program running
which captures one of the keys captured by xbindkeys.
It seems that there is a conflict, and xbindkeys can't
grab all the keys defined in its configuration file."

Comment: Try again after disabling the shortcut from the window manager. That error means that both the window manager and `xbindkeys` are trying to bind the same key. If you disable the WM one, you can at least use `xbindkeys` and then you can see whether this actually helps or not.

Comment: @terdon I did, to no avail - I'd probably have to eliminate _any_ shortcut involving the Win-key, and then use `xbindkeys` to control the Window manager as well :-/

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be necessary. I use `xbindkeys` with my CInnamon for one Ctrl+foo shortcut and other Ctrl+bar shortcuts defined by the WM work fine. On the other hand, I haven't been a Windows user for almost 20 years so I don't have any habits to unlearn. I therefore tend to use Alt combinations instead. Wouldn't that be a simpler solution? Alt is right next to Win after all.

Comment: XD Nah, it's more a matter of principle - then I'd want to use Alt alone for the menu and alt+arrows for the resizing, which would probably fail the same way

Comment: Install [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) from the arch repositories and follow the instructions on this [SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214956/how-to-set-a-single-modifier-key-as-a-shortcut-in-openbox/215259#215259). While this question was meant for openbox, it works completely fine in xfce, too.

Comment: @Devon Looks good to me, why don't post this as answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered?

Comment: One thing I observed in my case while playing with this issue is that  shortcuts that stop working after binding whisker menu to Super key are those defined for the 'Window Manager Actions' (defined in Window Manager's Keyboard tab).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) to fix this (KDE users might be interested in [ksuperkey](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey)). While this small background daemon is useful to bind keys to another (combination of) keys, it also comes along with the feature of running actions only when keys are released, not when they are pressed.

1. [Install](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-software-in-various-linux-distros/) [xcape](https://repology.org/project/xcape/versions).
2. Assign <kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd> to a placeholder shortcut like <kbd>⎈ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or any other shortcut that is not taken by another application:

   ```
   xcape -e 'Super_L=Shift_L|Control_L|Alt_L|Super_L|D'
   ```
3. Make sure to start whiskermenu with the same shortcut. Do this by adding a shortcut in *Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts*.
4. Add your xcape command in *Settings > Session and Startup > Application Autostart* to automatically start xcape when xfce boots up.

Comment: Interesting Xfce bug: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7845

Comment: For The newcomers here, you need to add the whole `xcape` command to the startup settings, like the example he provided: `xcape -e 'Super_L=Control_L|Shift_L|Alt_L|Super_L|Escape'` Thanks for putting this together for us, @Devon

Comment: Here's the new home of that "interesting Xfce bug" on GitLab: https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/libxfce4ui/-/issues/1